# Permission precedence: Group vs Individual

Tags: 2013, list, permissions, groups

Is there a way to have an individual's permission level that is lower than a permission level granted to a group that the individual resides in?

Example: A user is in a group with write permissions, but that particular user should only have read permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible when a user has been granted group and individual permissions. The higher permission level trumps always.

You can have different permissions throughout the site, so they could have read to the site but write to a library. But in that scenario, you need to make sure the user has only been granted access either by group or individually, not both.