# Access Conflict on SharePoint 2010

Tags: permissions

While checking the permission of a user in SharePoint I found he has all access level means to say he has `Full access, Design,contribute and read access` on that site.

My question is in this case, what will be his actual access on this site ?

Comment: If he has Full access, he will have Full access

Answer (score 1):

The highest level permission level will take precedence. In your case, the user has Full Control permission.

[Similar answer here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145017/permission-precedence-group-vs-individual)

[More on SharePoint permission levels](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Understanding-permission-levels-in-SharePoint-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer for what will be his actual access on this site ?

- He has a Full Control because it's the highest permission level

Check also, [Understanding permission levels in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Understanding-permission-levels-in-SharePoint-87ecbb0e-6550-491a-8826-c075e4859848)